# Permission denied

Tags: centos, openstack, chef

I was trying to create and bootstrap an instance on openstack with chef using this command:

`sudo knife openstack server create -N jenkins_openstack -f 0eb9c50a-07b9-4fc1-aa33-f6bd66c6bc7b --network-ids 7d5c5d7e-e447-4b22-a5f8-5dbfb53c2128 --openstack-ssh-key-id mmm --openstack-floating-ip -r 'role[jenkins]' --environment production -i /root/.ssh/mmm.pem --ssh-user centos  --bootstrap-install-command ' sudo sh -c  'echo 192.168.103.194 chef.server.com   >> /etc/hosts''`

but this doesn't work and gives this error:

-bash: /etc/hosts: Permission denied

Any ideas?

Comment: i had to use this command : `--bootstrap-install-command ' sudo sh -c  'echo 192.168.103.194 chef.server.com   >> /etc/hosts''` cause my instance doesn't see chef

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes do not nest:

```
--bootstrap-install-command ' sudo sh -c  'echo 192.168.103.194 chef.server.com   >> /etc/hosts''
```

The argument to `--bootstrap-install-command` will be `sudo sh -c 'echo`,
then stray tokens `192.168.103.194 chef.server.com >>/etc/hosts`
will remain, resulting in a non-sudo attempt to append to
file `/etc/hosts`. This explains the error message you received.

Try this instead:

```
--bootstrap-install-command 'sudo sh -c "echo 192.168.103.194 chef.server.com >>/etc/hosts"'
```